# Webdev - should hits and log data be in a database, or files?

Tags: php, logging

I've got the following user data for my site:

1) Hit IP, location

2) Login name, attempt info

3) Download attempt info

Is it better to keep this information in individual files, per day, or in a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is a trade-off.

With files, they are easy to move around, easy to export to other systems and simple to parse.

With a database you have easy searching, reporting, and security.

It is up to you to balance those priorities.

Comment: Some good points here; gonna give you the accept.  All the other answers were good too though, +1 everyone thanks for the help.

Comment: @Steve, Curious what you decided to do.

Comment: Went with the database solution since I'm more interested in statistical queries, permanence, and security.  If this fails horribly I'll come back and update this question.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Files are the optimal store for logging data. You don't need to access them daily, nor do you want to run queries on them usually (that would be the deciding factor). Usual log data is textual and informative, not structured. And the file API is best suited to append log data. (It's faster, but you shouldn't base the decision on performance aspects however.)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why not to "base the decision on performance aspects"?

Comment: @Steve: It's seldomly measurable. You don't want to log every single event anyway, and unless there are a few million users it won't make a difference. That's why I think it's more important to decide solely on the log structure / format / evaluation method.

Answer (score 2):

Keep them in the database, it's easier and more efficient, especially if you're reading the data for statistics/other stuff.  A database also prevents file write locks.  There is a limited set of things that should be stored in files: mostly large amounts of binary data, e.x. images.

A side note, make sure `login name` points at the/a primary key of the users table (be that an auto-increment integer column, or the username; whatever you set it to).  This will increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

Files much more preffered: on top what previous users said usually you log at the beginnig of script, if your database think to long it will affect performance of the script, logging to file will be faster in many casses.

And if fast and convinient reporting is needed you can always load data from file to database as when it needed or as cron job